# (gcloud.functions.deploy) permission denied when deploying function with specific service account

Tags: function, deployment, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy Google Cloud Functions using a different service account.  I have the service account properties saved to a json file.  I swapped out the values to make it easier to read.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/keys/mynewserviceaccount.json"

gcloud functions deploy MyFunction \
--runtime python37 \
--entry-point MyFunction \
--source src \
--service-account mynewserviceaccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
--verbosity debug \
--stage-bucket staging.projectname.appspot.com \
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write \
--trigger-resource "projects/projectname/databases/(default)/documents/User/{userId}" &
```

mynewserviceaccount has the following roles.  I've tried a few others and haven't had success.
- Cloud Functions Admin
- Cloud Functions Service Agent
- Errors Writer
- Service Account User
- Logs Writer
- Pub/Sub Subscriber

I've also ran 
    gcloud auth activate-service-account mynewserviceaccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file "/path/to/keys/mynewserviceaccount.json"

When I run this, I get:
    ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]

When I try to find "gcloud.functions.deploy" in the Roles list, I don't see it.  I don't know if this is an issue with documentation or an issue with the code.

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration

Comment: This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration)  states that you have to do an extra step. 
Assign the user the IAM Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the Cloud Functions Runtime service account. Have you done that already?

Comment: This worked.  Thanks!  It'd be useful to move this UI to an easier to discover spot.

Comment: Posted a formal answer, please marked it as correct for other people to see. Glad I helped

Answer (score 8):

if this was when running `gcloud builds submit` command, the most likely reason is `Cloud Functions Developer` role not being enabled for the `Cloud Build` service.

1. Navigate to Cloud Build > Settings
2. Enable Cloud Functions Developer Role

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration) on cloud functions states that if you want to deploy a function with a service account you have to do an extra step.

You must assign the user the IAM Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the Cloud Functions Runtime service account.

[image]